# How to separate this two? i mean 2 different account

Tags: java

The "Invalid Username or Password" Always Pop-up.

What i'm trying to do is, two accounts must successfully login, but the error is i cant login the second account.
Please lend me some help!
what am i lacking ?
Some suggestions?
Please help me!

```
import java.io.*;
public class Sample {
public static void main (String[] Ropher) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String username;
    String password;

    String user1 = "Geoddie";
    String user2 = "Rosiel";
    String pass1 = "123";
    String pass2 = "914";

    int j = 1;
    int x = 1;

    System.out.print("Username: ");
    username = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Password: ");
    password = br.readLine();

    while (x <=3)
    {


    if ((username.equals(user1)) && (password.equals(pass1))){
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        break;
    }else if (!(username.equals(user1)) && !(password.equals(pass1))){
        System.out.println("Invalid Username or Password!");

    }else if (!(username.equals(user1))){
        System.out.println("Invalid Username!");

    }else if (!(password.equals(pass1))){
        System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
        x++;
        //
        //
        //

        }
    }

    while (j<=3){



     if ((username.equals(user2)) && (password.equals(pass2))){
        System.out.println("Welcome!");

        break;


    }else if (!(username.equals(user2))){
        System.out.println("Invalid Username!");

    }else if (!(password.equals(pass2))){
    System.out.println("Invalid Password!");

    }
    else if (!(username.equals(user2)) && !(password.equals(pass2))){
        System.out.println("Invalid Username or Password!"); 
    j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the PHP code here?

Comment: Sorry sir.
i just clicked the suggested tags.

Comment: I'm trying to work on with your code. I really need you to cooperate, I have a question. Why do you have `x <= 3` ?

Comment: Security note: it is never a good idea to reveal, in any way, whether either the username or password were actually correct. If either or both are wrong, give exactly the same generic error message in each case.

Comment: < = 3 for attempts?
my teacher says that 3 incorrect login the program terminates.

Comment: with your code, i can't understand why you had looped your condition. Are you trying to set a 3 valid attempts for the user to log-in?

I also agree with @NathanTuggy.

Comment: Yeah, but my instructor said that if the username is invalid the output should says invalid username same with password. @wwwDELL.

Comment: @GeoddieChristopherOrtiz: Your instructor should probably be teaching better practice, even in applications that are never intended for serious use, but oh well. Point is, any time you're trying to actually *secure* anything with a password that's more interesting than cat videos, make sure attackers can't tell that their guesses were half-right.

Answer (score 1):

How could you login to your second account ?

What you are doing in second comparison is

```
user2 = "Rosiel"
username = "Geoddie"
```

You are trying to compare `user2.equals(username)`. Since you first got successfully logged in so your `username` variable contains the value `Geoddie`.

Now you are using the same username to match `user2` which contains the value `Rosiel`.

You should also put

```
    System.out.print("Username: ");
    username = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Password: ");
    password = br.readLine();
```

before

```
while (j<=3){
```

Comment: Should i make another variable?

Comment: @GeoddieChristopherOrtiz, Updated the answer. That will work

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

1. As TAsk said, the `readLine()` must be inside the loop
2. The condition `!(username.equals(user1)) && !(password.equals(pass1))` IS NOT equal to `!(username.equals(user1) && password.equals(pass1))` (the negation of the success condition). If you want to make a logic negation you must change the connector also, that would be: `!(username.equals(user1) && password.equals(pass1)) = !username.equals(user1) || !password.equals(pass1)` (change AND by OR). Note that your message is "Invalid Username OR password"
3. The sentence `x++` is just in one condition. For the first validation, you are incrementing the counter only when you have incorrect password. `x++` must be OUTSIDE the conditional structure.

Review your code with this suggestions and let us know how it goes. Hope this helps. Best regards

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fully working log-in then you should do this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Sample {
public static void main (String[] Ropher) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String username;
    String password;

    String user1 = "Geoddie";
    String user2 = "Rosiel";
    String pass1 = "123";
    String pass2 = "914";

    int x = 1;

    while (x <=3)
    {

        System.out.print("Username: ");
        username = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        password = br.readLine();


        if ((username.equals(user1)) && (password.equals(pass1))){
            System.out.println("Welcome! "+user1);
            break;
        }else if ((username.equals(user2)) && (password.equals(pass2))){
            System.out.println("Welcome! "+user2);
            break;
        }else if (!(username.equals(user1)) && !(password.equals(pass1)) || !(username.equals(user2)) && !(password.equals(pass2))){
            System.out.println("\nInvalid Username or Password!");
            System.out.println("You have "+(3-x)+" login attempts left.");
            if ((3-x) == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
            }
            System.out.println();
            x++;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

What i did in this code is that

**1.** the program prompts the user for their username and password

**2.** if the username and password matched it will display a message `"Welcome"`

**3.** else if it's not found displays a message `"Invalid username and password"`

**4.** and then shows how many remaining login attempts left

**5.** and if it reaches the maximum attempts which is 3 then it will end the program and displays `"Goodbye"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if i would like to be more specific like if the username is invalid put "Invalid Username!".

is it possible ?

Comment: As what @Nathan Tuggy said on the comment, having that type of error message is not a good idea for it would be easy for the hacker to hack your account.